# surpress output of single line, multi command Makefile recipe

Tags: npm, makefile, output

I would like to surpress the output of certain commands in my Makefile

For instance I have a target, stagel

```
stagel:
    cd scripts && npm list body-parser || npm install body-parser
    node scripts/app.js
```

I'd like to surpress the output of first line in the target.

I tried, `@cd scripts && npm list body-parser || npm install body-parser`, but I still got the output. I also tried appending `@` to each npm command, but got, `@npm: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this command is not right:

```
cd scripts && npm list body-parser || npm install body-parser
```

This says, "run `cd scripts`: if the `cd` works, run `npm list body-parser` and if the `cd` fails, run `npm install body-parser`".  I don't know what you're trying to do for sure but I suspect what you want to say is, "first `cd scripts`, then run `npm list body-parser` and if that fails run `npm install body-parser`".  To do that you'll need something like this:

```
cd scripts && { npm list body-parser || npm install body-parser; }
```

It's not clear what you mean by "supporess the output of first line".  Do you mean, you don't want `make` to print out the command line it is running?  Or do you mean, you don't want the output from the command to be shown?

If the former then your attempt `@cd ...` will do that.  Since you weren't happy with that I can only assume you mean the latter.

Make does not have anything to say about the output that commands you run generate.  If you want to suppress that output you have to do it yourself, using normal shell redirection operations.  For example:

```
stagel:
        cd scripts && { npm list body-parser || npm install body-parser; } >/dev/null
        node scripts/app.js
```